# jQuery move specific select list option to bottom

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have the following markup:-

```
<select name="a" id="a">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option Bottom</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <optgroup label="Test">
       <option>Option A</option>
       <option>Option B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Using jQuery I wish to move the option `Option Bottom` to the bottom of the list. The `<optgroup>` must however stay at the very bottom.

So the markup needs to read like this:-

```
<select name="a" id="a">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option Bottom</option>
    <optgroup label="Test">
       <option>Option A</option>
       <option>Option B</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I can get the options excluding the `<optgroup>` by using
`$options = $('#a').children('option');`

How would I grab the `Option Bottom` option, and how would I move it to the bottom of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#a > option').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML == "Option Bottom";
}).insertBefore($('#a  optgroup'));​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXNV3/3/)

Comment: @generalexception. nope, unless the `<opgroup>` isn't there when you run the code. can you reproduce the not working scenario at http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#a option').each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Option Bottom') {
        $(this).insertBefore('#a optgroup');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `filter` if you like, the `insertBefore` function works with jQuery object.